# Obtaining date without the time parameters

Tags: momentjs

using

```
moment().add(1, 'days')
```

gives a date that looks like

```
2014-12-19 01:23:56.000Z
```

How does one obtain

```
2014-12-19 00:20:00.000Z
```

instead ?

i.e what modification does one have to do to the moment() call inorder to obtain this output

Answer (score 0):

```
moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day')
```

will return

```
2014-12-19 00:00:00.000Z
```

and

```
moment().add(1, 'day').startOf('day').add(20, 'hour')
```

will return

```
2014-12-19 00:20:00.000Z
```